# Bash: if vs. case

Tags: bash

Below I use `if` statements and `case` statements to arrange the order of my arguments below to ease the repetitive typing I do with rsync. Would a `case` statement be wiser for the `if` blocks below? If so, how?

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync="rsync -vrtzhP --delete"
localmus=" /cygdrive/c/Users/user/Music/Zune/"
remotemus=" 10.252.252.254::Zune/"
localcal=" /cygdrive/c/Users/user/calibre/"
remotecal=" 10.252.252.254::calibre/"
dry=" -n"

if [ $1 == "zune" ] && [ $2 == "tohere" ]
then
    toex=$rsync$remotemus$localmus
fi

if [ $1 == "zune" ] && [ $2 == "tothere" ]
then
    toex=$rsync$localmus$remotemus
fi

if [ $1 == "calibre" ] && [ $2 == "tohere" ]
then
    toex=$rsync$remotecal$localcal
fi

if [ $1 == "calibre" ] && [ $2 == "tothere" ]
then
    toex=$rsync$localcal$remotecal
fi


if [[ $3 == "dry" ]]
then
    toex=$toex$dry
fi

echo
echo $toex
echo
echo "Execute? y/n: "
read answer
case $answer in
    y)
        eval $toex
    ;;
    n)  
        echo NO!
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Youcould concatenate $1 and $2 to switch on it.

Answer (score 3):

You could concatenate $1 and $2 to switch on it.

```
case "$1 $2" in
"zune toHere")
  toex=$rsync$localmus$remotemus
  ;;
"calibre toHere")
  toex=$rsync$remotecal$localcal
  ;;
*)
  echo "Unknown command $1 $2"
  exit 2
  ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

A `case` statement would produce more readable and compact code here:

```
case "$1-$2" in
"zune-tohere")
    toex="$rsync$remotemus$localmus"
    ;;
...
esac
```

Comment: It would also be better to build the command in an array rather than by concatenating variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to handle the two together, and *absolutely* no reason to use `eval`:

```
remote=10.252.252.254::
local=/cygdrive/c/Users/user/

do_rsync () {
  rsync -vrtzhP --delete "$1" "$2"
}

case $1 in
  zune)
    remote+=Zune/
    local+=/Music/Zune
    ;;
  calibre)
    remote+=calibre/
    local+=/calibre
    ;;
  *) echo "Unknown transfer type: $1" >&2
     return 1
     ;;
esac

case $2 in
  tohere)
    do_rsync "$remote" "$local" ;;
  tothere)
    do_rsync "$local" "$remote" ;;
  *) echo "Unknown transfer direction: $2" >&2
     return 1
esac
```